# Splitting coax cable for PC tuner

Tags: hdtv, tuner-card, coaxial

I have an HDTV connected with HDMI from a DISH Network VIP612 DVR Receiver. I want to split the coaxial connection from the DVR to my [Hauppauge 1200 WinTV HVR-850 HDTV Tuner Stick](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00169CDUY). What splitter and coaxial cable (needs to transmit audio and video) should I get to make this a watchable TV  on my computer?

Comment: which coax.  coax input to the DVR (presumably from the dish)?

Comment: the coax needs to go into the TV Tuner.

Comment: yeah, got that. but you want to split it to do that.  so where is it coming from, and going to, now?

Comment: i need a split the signal from the dvr to the tuner. So i need a coax connected to the dvr and one connected to the tuner. i need a splitter for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am confused, you say you want to split the coax but you aren't telling us what coax you are talking about.

You have:

```
[Dish] -- coax -- [DVR] -- hdmi -- [TV]
```

And you want:

```
[Dish] -- coax -- [DVR] -- hdmi -- [TV]
           |
           +----- [PC] ----------- [Monitor]
```

I don't think you can split the coax from the dish and feed it to your Hauppauge. Pretty sure it is just an over the air HDTV tuner, not a Sat receiver. If you could do this, you wouldn't need to pay Dish :)

Comment: +1 for ascii art, and because this is my interpretation as well.

Comment: The tuner has a coax input. What u stated "[Dish] -- coax -- [DVR] -- hdmi -- [TV]
           |
           +----- [PC] ----------- [Monitor]" is correct. Thats what I want.

Comment: Yes, the tuner has a coax input, but the signal it is expecting is from an OTA antenna, not the signal that is sent from LNB to Receiver (which as mentioned by @Wil is a two way signal and not split-able -- but may be multiplex-able with the right equipment [some DirecTV can], but that is another thing all together and doesn't help you.

Comment: So what can I do to get tv on the computer thru the tuner?

Comment: I don't think you can with that tuner. Look into upgrading to the HD DuoDVR™ VIP®922 with TV Everywhere when it comes out, it appears to have a built in SlingBox. http://www.dishnetwork.com/tveverywhere/default.aspx

Comment: I dont think thats an option for me. There has got to be a way to get TV on computer.

Comment: You could get a sling box (http://www.slingbox.com/) but this piggybacks off your current receiver (goes inbetween the receiver and the TV), it won't let you watch two different live programs at once.

Answer (score 1):

If it is anything like Sky digital in the UK, this is not possible.

(Example based on Sky Digital) The two cables are each connected to a different output on the LNB (the part at the end of the dish) and it is not a one way signal - the box can only receive on either 11Ghz or 12Ghz then scan vertical or horizontal at once (so one of four).

This is why when you switch between some channels, it is instant and when you switch between others, it takes a little time as it has to refocus and tune.

The best thing you can do is buy a switch box so that you can send the signal to one of the other.

[image]

Alternatively, the best (but hardest) solution is to upgrade your LNB to one with more ports then run some new cable. Then you can use all your devices at once.

[image]

Comment: this sounds logical but i don't have the experience to verify.  is Sky Digital sent in the clear?  i'm fairly sure US satellite TV is encrypted (the DVR or other set-top-box contains the decoding hardware).